# Sequelize find based on association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

How would I use Sequelize to find all people where a column in the relation satisfies a condition?

An example would be to find all Books whose author's last name is 'Hitchcock'.  The book schema contains a hasOne relation with the Author's table.

Edit: I understand how this could be done with a raw SQL query, but looking for another approach

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's a working sample of how to user Sequelize to get all `Books` by an `Author` with a certain last name. It looks quite a bit more complicated than it is, because I am defining the Models, associating them, syncing with the database (to create their tables), and then creating dummy data in those new tables. Look for the `findAll` in the middle of the code to see specifically what you're after.

```
    module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Author = sequelize.define('Author', {

        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }

    })

    var Book = sequelize.define('Book', {

        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        title: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        }

    })

    var firstAuthor;
    var secondAuthor;

    Author.hasMany(Book)
    Book.belongsTo(Author)

    Author.sync({ force: true })
        .then(function() {
            return Book.sync({ force: true });
        })
        .then(function() {
            return Author.create({firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Testerson'});
        })
        .then(function(author1) {
            firstAuthor=author1;
            return Author.create({firstName: 'The Invisible', lastName: 'Hand'});
        })
        .then(function(author2) {
            secondAuthor=author2
            return Book.create({AuthorId: firstAuthor.id, title: 'A simple book'});
        })
        .then(function() {
            return Book.create({AuthorId: firstAuthor.id, title: 'Another book'});
        })
        .then(function() {
            return Book.create({AuthorId: secondAuthor.id, title: 'Some other book'});
        })
        .then(function() {
            // This is the part you're after.
            return Book.findAll({
                where: {
                   'Authors.lastName': 'Testerson'
                },
                include: [
                    {model: Author, as: Author.tableName}
                ]
            });
        })
        .then(function(books) { 
            console.log('There are ' + books.length + ' books by Test Testerson')
        });
  }
```

Comment: This did not work for me, I think as of sequelize 2.0, the where clause must be placed in the include array member, such as `include: [{model:..., where:...}]`

Comment: Nevertheless, the answer gave me hope that this is somehow possible so I pursued to finding a solution :)

Comment: I can confirm that as of Sequelize 2.0 the `where` clause must be inside the `include`, just like: `include: [ { model: ..}, where: { 'Author.lastName: 'Testerson' }]`

Comment: @AndreyPopov, but how in this case to find Books by title or by Author.lastName?

Comment: `Book.findAll({ include: [ model: Author, where: { 'lastName': 'Testerson' } ] });` Should be working fine.. :)

Comment: Is it better practise to keep all models in one file? Like above? Or put them in separate files? @AndreyPopov

Comment: I would strongly recommend putting models in different files. Then just load all files in a directory and they will self-initialize :) Otherwise you'll get pretty doomed after a while (thousands of lines in one file)

Comment: As some others commented before, the query doesn't work with `where:{'Authors.lastName': 'Testerson'}` outside `include`, as in this answer. Sequelize compiles it as ``[...] AND `Authors.lastName` = 'Testerson' [...]``.

Comment: How would this work if the relationship was a many to many?
`Author.belongsToMany(Book)`
`Book.belongsToMany(Author)`
A second table (something like "BookAuthor") gets created, and syntax like `where: { 'Authors.lastName': 'Testerson' }` doesn't seem to work anymore...

Comment: you don't need the Authors inside the where clause: ```{ 'lastName': 'Testerson' }```

Comment: putting `where` inside `include` builds a query like this: `LEFT OUTER JOIN Authors ON Books.authorId = Authors.id AND Authors.lastName = 'Testerson'`, and the result is quite different from `LEFT OUTER JOIN Authors ON Books.authorId = Authors.id ... WHERE Authors.lastName = 'Testerson'`. I'm not sure how to achieve the latter query with sequelize.

Comment: how to use the same way when having many to many relations since you have an external table instead of columns to test on ?

Answer (score 29):

In the newest version of Sequilize (5.9.0) the method proposed by @c.hill does not work.

Now you need to do the following:

```js
return Book.findAll({
    where: {
        '$Authors.lastName$': 'Testerson'
    },
    include: [
        {model: Author, as: Author.tableName}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Where do I find the documentation for this?

Comment: I didn't find any documentation, but this worked like a charm!

Comment: @lordvcs Here: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level

Comment: I miss good old plain SQL when it takes me 2 hours to accomplish this with Sequelize

Comment: pagination does not work in this

Answer (score 14):

For documentation!

Check the eager loading section

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html

For the above answers! You can find it in the doc at the following title

**Complex where clauses at the top-level**

### From the doc:

To obtain top-level WHERE clauses that involve nested columns, Sequelize provides a way to reference nested columns: the '$nested.column$' syntax.

It can be used, for example, to move the where conditions from an included model from the ON condition to a top-level WHERE clause.

```js
User.findAll({
  where: {
    '$Instruments.size$': { [Op.ne]: 'small' }
  },
  include: [{
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments'
  }]
});
```

Generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  `user`.`id`,
  `user`.`name`,
  `Instruments`.`id` AS `Instruments.id`,
  `Instruments`.`name` AS `Instruments.name`,
  `Instruments`.`size` AS `Instruments.size`,
  `Instruments`.`userId` AS `Instruments.userId`
FROM `users` AS `user`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tools` AS `Instruments` ON
  `user`.`id` = `Instruments`.`userId`
WHERE `Instruments`.`size` != 'small';
```

For a better understanding of all differences between the inner where option (used inside an include), with and without the required option, and a top-level where using the $nested.column$ syntax, below we have four examples for you:

```js
// Inner where, with default `required: true`
await User.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments',
    where: {
      size: { [Op.ne]: 'small' }
    }
  }
});

// Inner where, `required: false`
await User.findAll({
  include: {
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments',
    where: {
      size: { [Op.ne]: 'small' }
    },
    required: false
  }
});

// Top-level where, with default `required: false`
await User.findAll({
  where: {
    '$Instruments.size$': { [Op.ne]: 'small' }
  },
  include: {
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments'
  }
});

// Top-level where, `required: true`
await User.findAll({
  where: {
    '$Instruments.size$': { [Op.ne]: 'small' }
  },
  include: {
    model: Tool,
    as: 'Instruments',
    required: true
  }
});
```

Generated SQLs, in order:

```sql
-- Inner where, with default `required: true`
SELECT [...] FROM `users` AS `user`
INNER JOIN `tools` AS `Instruments` ON
  `user`.`id` = `Instruments`.`userId`
  AND `Instruments`.`size` != 'small';

-- Inner where, `required: false`
SELECT [...] FROM `users` AS `user`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tools` AS `Instruments` ON
  `user`.`id` = `Instruments`.`userId`
  AND `Instruments`.`size` != 'small';

-- Top-level where, with default `required: false`
SELECT [...] FROM `users` AS `user`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `tools` AS `Instruments` ON
  `user`.`id` = `Instruments`.`userId`
WHERE `Instruments`.`size` != 'small';

-- Top-level where, `required: true`
SELECT [...] FROM `users` AS `user`
INNER JOIN `tools` AS `Instruments` ON
  `user`.`id` = `Instruments`.`userId`
WHERE `Instruments`.`size` != 'small';
```

And that give us a good look how the **join**'s are done!