# sequelize where relation is null

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an issue with sequelize. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
return pointsTransaction.findAndCountAll({
    where:{
        user_id: userId
    },
    limit: opts.limit,
    offset: opts.offset,
    include:[{
        model:sequelize.models.pointsPendingtransaction
    }]
});
```

The generated query looks like that:

```
SELECT "pointsTransaction".*,
"pointsPendingtransactions"."transaction_ptr_id" AS "pointsPendingtransactions.transactionPtrId",
"pointsPendingtransactions"."is_active" AS "pointsPendingtransactions.isActive",
"pointsPendingtransactions"."transaction_id" AS "pointsPendingtransactions.transaction_id" 
FROM (
SELECT "pointsTransaction"."id",
"pointsTransaction"."date_time" AS "dateTime",
"pointsTransaction"."details",
"pointsTransaction"."points",
"pointsTransaction"."user_id" 
FROM "points_transaction" AS "pointsTransaction" 
WHERE "pointsTransaction"."user_id" = 10002 LIMIT 1000
) AS "pointsTransaction" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "points_pendingtransaction" AS "pointsPendingtransactions" 
ON "pointsTransaction"."id" = "pointsPendingtransactions"."transaction_id"
```

So in SQL I would just need to add that line at the end of my query to make it work: `WHERE "pointsPendingtransactions"."transaction_id" IS null`

So my question is, how can I do that with sequelize? I tried many different ways but no one worked...

Comment: Something like:
include:[{
  model:sequelize.models.pointsPendingtransaction,
  where:{transaction_id:null}
}] should work althought i haven't tried this myself

Comment: I tried it, also tried it with some having based on a count but nothing is working. I suspect an error due to "findAndCountAll"

Comment: What error do you get when you try Molda's suggestion?

Comment: i know its late, but you can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005763/load-items-where-relation-is-null-in-sequelize/48008961#48008961

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Sequelize's symbol operators from Sequelize.Op then ...

```js
return pointsTransaction.findAndCountAll({
    where:{
        user_id: userId
    },
    limit: opts.limit,
    offset: opts.offset,
    include:[{
        model:sequelize.models.pointsPendingtransaction,
        where: {
            transaction_id: {
              // "$eq" changes to "[Op.eq]"
              [Op.eq]: null
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Try to do next

```js
        where: {
            transaction_id: {
              $eq: null
            }
        }
```

to generate `IS NULL`

---

```js
return pointsTransaction.findAndCountAll({
    where:{
        user_id: userId
    },
    limit: opts.limit,
    offset: opts.offset,
    include:[{
        model:sequelize.models.pointsPendingtransaction,
        where: {
            transaction_id: {
              $eq: null
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: All this does is put an extra condition on the join, it does not do what he's wanting.  Tried it myself.  A where clause is needed after the left outer join but putting a condition in the outer where clause adds it to this section `WHERE "pointsTransaction"."user_id" = 10002 LIMIT 1000`

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Sequelize 5.22.4. You should use Op.is instead of eq.

eq will produce a:

> (...) where transactions_id=""  (...)

While Op.is will produce a

> (...) where transaction_id is NULL (...)

```
return pointsTransaction.findAndCountAll({
    where:{
        user_id: userId
    },
    limit: opts.limit,
    offset: opts.offset,
    include:[{
        model:sequelize.models.pointsPendingtransaction,
        where: {
            transaction_id: {
              // "$is" changes to "[Op.is]"
              [Op.is]: null
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**`$eq` and `[Op.eq]` are not needed tested as of Sequelize 6.14.0**

It works without them, just as it does for other values, e.g.:

```
where: {
  transaction_id: null
}
```

produces `IS NULL`.

You do need the magic syntax for `IS NOT NULL` however as usual, achieved with:

```
where: {
  transaction_id: {
    [Op.ne]: null
  }
}
```

The `where` inside `include` part of answer is then the same as for other non null values, see e.g.: [Sequelize find based on association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838433/sequelize-find-based-on-association)